# Timestamp difference between rows in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

In PostgreSQL I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE cubenotification.newnotification
(
  idnewnotification serial NOT NULL,
  contratto text,
  idlocation numeric,
  typology text,
  idpost text,
  iduser text,
  idobject text,
  idwhere text,
  status text DEFAULT 'valid'::text,
  data_crea timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  username text,
  usersocial text,
  url text,
  apikey text,
  CONSTRAINT newnotification_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idnewnotification )
)
```

Let's say that typology field can be "owned_task" or "fwd_task". 
What I'd like to get from DB is the timestamp difference in seconds strictly between data_crea of the row with typology "fwd_task" and data_crea of the row with typology "owned_task" for every couple "idobject,iduser", and I'd like to get also the EXTRACT(WEEK FROM data_crea)) as "weeks", grouping the results by "weeks". My problem is principally about performing the timestamp ordered difference between two rows with same idobject, same iduser and different typology.

EDIT:
Here some sample data

[image: sample data]

and sqlfiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6cd64/2

Comment: Some sample data would be *very helpful*. Possibly as [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: sorry, now there are sample data. Building the example in sqlfiddle I made mistake about IDNEWNOTIFICATION values, they should have been inserted from 16 to 1 other than from 1 to 16

Comment: sqlfiddle is very helpful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the **JOIN of two subselects**:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM o.data_crea) AS owned_week
     , iduser, idobject
     , EXTRACT('epoch' FROM (o.data_crea - f.data_crea)) AS diff_in_sek
FROM  (SELECT * FROM newnotification WHERE typology = 'owned_task') o
JOIN  (SELECT * FROM newnotification WHERE typology = 'fwd_task')   f
                                                         USING (iduser, idobject)
ORDER  BY 1,4
```

[->sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6cd64/5)

I order by week and timestamp difference. The week number is based on the week of 'owned_task'.

This assumes there is exactly *one* row for 'owned_task' and one for 'fwd_task' per `(iduser, idobject)`, not one per week. Your specification leaves room for interpretation.